# How sites build zip files online for download?

Tags: asp.net, zip

I want to know that how many sites like jqueryui, etc. build online zip packages for download.
And how it can be done in asp.net ?

Comment: Do you mean compressing javascript or creating a zip?

Comment: Ya, compressing js and creating zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take the compress as minified, and not as encrypted and compress on string.

As alternative I like to propose the **Microsoft Ajax Minified 4.0**, that I use it with  sussex on very complicate and big javascript files (including jQuery) for real time compress them/minified them...

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584

and the next to zip it, I suggest SharpZipLib but also the **DotNetZip**

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

To compress/minify javascript files you could use the [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) which has a [.NET port](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/). The [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) is also worth checking. You could [use it online](http://madskristensen.net/post/Use-Googles-Closure-Compiler-in-C.aspx) or compile its JAR package to .NET assembly using [ikvmc](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html). To create a zip file you may take a look at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).